# Tengo un código de formateo de número

Tags: javascript, script

El problema es que sí me separa en decimales ej 25,42 automáticamente escribo 2542. si quiero vender un caro en 600 $ el automáticamente coloca 6.00 pero si agrego otros 00 para que sea 600.00 me lo coloca de la siguiente manera ( 6.00.00 ), pero a su vez está bien por que quiero vender algo en 6.24$ y lo hace automáticamente el código :

```
        function format(input) {
            var num = input.value.replace(/\./g, '');
            if (!isNaN(num)) {
                num = num.toString().split('').reverse().join('').replace(/(?=\d*\.?)(\d{3})/g, '$1.');
                num = num.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/^[\.]/, '');
                input.value = num;
            }
        }

<label for="message-text" class = "control-label" > precio: < /label>

<input type = "num"  class = "form-control"onKeyUp = "format(this)"
        onchange = "format(this)" id = "precio" >
```

Comment: Por favor, redacta mejor la pregunta porque no se entiende bien el problema. [ask]

Comment: Te recomiendo que revises esta función de js, creo es lo mas ideal para tu caso. [Number-toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/toLocaleString)

Comment: Pregunta duplicada